# android facebooksdk login and status update in one click

Tags: android, facebook-android-sdk

I need to implement a share via facebook button within an android app. I read the official facebook sdk doc and the only way I can find to do this, is to first let user authenticate with a login button, and then let him update the status.
Since the facebook stuff is really marginal in the application, I'd like to find a way to let the user click only one time on a button (a custom one, not a com.facebook.widget.LoginButton), and then if already logged in, update the timeline, else, login and directly update timeline.

I really need to let the user accomplish the task in these steps:

-click on my button

-if not logged in, do login in dialog, new activity or whatever

-open a dialog (custom or from facebook sdk,doesn't matter) with an edittext for message and update/cancel buttons

I [read](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/03/android-facebook-connect-tutorial/) this tutorial, but everything used there seems to be deprecated (even when trying to initialize com.facebook.android.Facebook objects got a deprecated warning), so I wonder if there is a good way to implements a one click status update.

I already did it this way for twitter, there must be some way to do it for facebook too!